# How to hide sheet using xlsxwriter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I have created two excel sheets:

1. data sheet
2. graph sheet.

I am writing data to `data_sheet` and generating a graph in `graph_sheet`. I want to hide the `data_sheet`. But I am not able to do so using the function - `data_sheet.hide()`.

I am able to hide a blank sheet using that method but it doesn't seem to work for the `data_sheet`.

Comment: Is data_sheet the first sheet? Because it isn't possible in Excel to hide the "active" sheet, which is generally the first sheet, without activating another worksheet. See this example from the XlsxWriter docs: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_hide_sheet.html